# Elixir, phoenix : ** (CompileError) config/config.exs:8: module Config is not loaded and could not be found

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, wsl-2

I don't understand why when I run any mix command in my wsl terminal from my phoenix project folder, I get the following error :

```
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:16:16] [ds:16:16:10] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

** (Mix.Config.LoadError) could not load config config/config.exs
    ** (CompileError) config/config.exs:8: module Config is not loaded and could not be found
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:168: Code.eval_string/3
    (mix) lib/mix/config.ex:161: Mix.Config.read!/1
```

Here is my config.exs :

```
import Config
config :timemanager,
  ecto_repos: [Timemanager.Repo]
config :timemanager, TimemanagerWeb.Endpoint,
  url: [host: "localhost"],
  render_errors: [view: TimemanagerWeb.ErrorView, accepts: ~w(json), layout: false],
  pubsub_server: Timemanager.PubSub,
  live_view: [signing_salt: "omLaBYXx"]
config :timemanager, Timemanager.Mailer, adapter: Swoosh.Adapters.Local
config :swoosh, :api_client, false
config :logger, :console,
  format: "$time $metadata[$level] $message\n",
  metadata: [:request_id]
config :phoenix, :json_library, Jason
import_config "#{config_env()}.exs"
```

I've tried to get and upgrade deps, but every mix command returns the same error. Besides, when I check elixir's version with "elixir -v", I get the following error:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,error},[{'Elixir.System',build,0,[{file,"lib/system.ex"},{line,172}]},{'Elixir.System',build_info,0,[{file,"lib/system.ex"},{line,164}]},{'Elixir.Kernel.CLI',parse_shared,2,[{file,"lib/kernel/cli.ex"},{line,153}]},{'Elixir.Kernel.CLI','shared_option?',3,[{file,"lib/kernel/cli.ex"},{line,113}]},{'Elixir.Kernel.CLI',main,1,[{file,"lib/kernel/cli.ex"},{line,14}]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ({{badmatch,error},[{Elixir.System,build,0,[{_},{_}]},{Elixir.System,build_info,0,[{_},{_}]},{Elixir.Kernel.CLI,parse_shared,2,[{_},{_}]},{Elixir.Kernel.CLI,shared_option?,
```

I'm pretty sure I have elixir installed, the "elixir" command returns the list of possible arguments. Could this be due to the fact I've installed erlang/elixir/phoenix from the windows terminal and I am now trying to use them from WSL ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you !

Comment: Check your version of Elixir and Erlang (aka OTP).  From your error msg, it looks like an older version: Erlang/OTP 20.  Support for `Config` is somewhat newer -- versions of Elixir before v1.12 included `use Mix.Config` in their configs instead of `import Config` -- different module.  Try `elixir --version` and paste the full result.

Comment: Erlang/OTP 25 [erts-13.0.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:16:16] [ds:16:16:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]

Elixir 1.14.1 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 25)  -- is what "elixir --version" returns. I am surprised that the command works, when I tried it previously it returned an error EDIT: Nevermind, it worked because I ran it in windows powershell. It does'nt work in wsl. It seems I have different versions installed on windows and ubuntu : even though I can't access my ubuntu elxir version, I can see it runs erlang otp 20, while windows uses otp 25

Comment: There's your problem: you're running different versions of Elixir and the app, it seems, is using an older version.  I would recommend updating your question with the above info -- it seems like it's really an installation issue that's causing you problems.  Maybe you can just alias the up-to-date version of `elixir` and everything will run normally.